# How to change text of label from another qml file?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

i want to change text of label which is present in another qml file

text.qml :

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 672
        height: 480
        color: "#ffffff"

        GroupBox {
            id: groupBox
            x: 56
            y: 155
            width: 537
            height: 285
            title: qsTr("Group box")

            Label {
                id: labelname
                x: 54
                y: 27
                text: qsTr("John")
            }

            Label {
                id: labelsname2
                x: 54
                y: 62
                text: qsTr("devid")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

i want to change labelname.text from main.qml

my main.qml is

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 190
        y: 127
        text: qsTr("change name")
        onClicked: {
            //i want to change text of labelname in text.qml
        }
    }
}
```

i want to send signal from cpp page ..signal contains name of person and these name is set to labelname in text.qml file

Comment: You really want to change it *in the file*, or do you want to change the corresponding label on the screen? The second seems easier, the first is a bit crazy.

Comment: i want to change labeltext when i hit change button..please help me

Comment: I'd like to help, but I don't think you really answered my question.

Comment: sorry... i want to change the corresponding label on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a property [alias](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html#property-aliases) to read from and write to a certain property of an element from outside the file:

MyForm.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Item {
    property alias labelNameText: labelname.text

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 672
        height: 480
        color: "#ffffff"

        GroupBox {
            id: groupBox
            x: 56
            y: 155
            width: 537
            height: 285
            title: qsTr("Group box")

            Label {
                id: labelname
                x: 54
                y: 27
                text: qsTr("John")
            }

            Label {
                id: labelsname2
                x: 54
                y: 62
                text: qsTr("devid")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how to use the alias:

main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MyForm {
        id: myForm
    }

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 190
        y: 127
        text: qsTr("change name")
        onClicked: {
            console.log('Name before change: ' + myForm.labelNameText);
            myForm.labelNameText = 'Herbert';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replay...can you please show example to write label.text property

Comment: i added some code, to show how it is used, but you can read all about it in the docs.